# Mongo Documents with ObjectId is not being updated and create new document with Mongo.ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, react-native, meteor

I am using react-native-meteor package to connect with meteor.My Mongodb collection contains document with ObjectId. When I get the collection in react-native client side, all my ObjectId is converted to string by default. Thus making me difficult to perform operation like update from react-native client side.

When I perform insert operation in react-native client side, The insert command creates _id as string while I want _id as Object ID.

Is there any method or class in this package(react-native-meteor) to convert _id to Obejct ID in react-native client side.

Comment: Could you post a piece of your code showing this insert command?

Comment: Please also emphasize where this is related to Meteor, which itself uses a slightly different approach for document ID's

Comment: Mongodb driver contain functionality to parse the string to objectId depends on platform .
Ex: nodejs mongoose driver provides `mongoose.Types.ObjectId("id-string")`;

Comment: I am using react-native-meteor package to connect with meteor. I am trying Meteor.collection('XYZ').insert(docs). This query creates _id as string while I need _id as Object ID.

Answer (score 0):

## Convert String to ObjectID MongoDB & NodeJS

var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID; // convert string to ObjectID in mongodb then I am able to convert string to ObjectId in nodejs mongodb native drive.